# Signing a message to make sure that it will not be tampered with when forwarded, without trusting the receivers?

Tags: rsa, dsa

Lets say there are 3 people.

- 1st signs a message and sends it to 2nd using public key encryption
- 1st deletes the message
- 1st tells 2nd to forward his message
- 2nd forwards the message to 3rd

How can 1st verify the message was forwarded untampered without trusting 2nd or 3rd and without finding out the message contents again?

A terrible idea is to have 3rd give his private key to a 4th who will confirm to 1st that his message was untampered.

I am new to this so if what I want to do is impossible a heads up would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Would simply storing a - possibly salted - hash over the message at A work? Then to verify C can recalculate the hash over the message and return it to A - possibly including the salt send to him by A into the hash calculation, of course. This would work even without a private key, although C could also sign the hash or return the signature & hash after verification to make it more secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this as a mixture of easy and impossible.  A standard digital signature will work to verify the contents, as long as the document+signature is sent to person 1 (or whoever wants to check the document)

The impossible part comes if you only want person 1 to only have the signature and not the document.  Even if person 1 keeps a copy of every signature, Person 2 can send a tampered document with the original signature.  Person 3 would know the document has been tampered, but if 3 wants to be part of the deception they can just send the original signature to person 1.